# Create .eml file in Development and Test Environment

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient, eml

The email templates are stored in database tables and we used SmtpClient to send e-Mail. Code is developed with C#.Net. Now client is requesting to create .eml file in the Development and other environments?

I want to know,

What is the need to creating .eml file in the different environments?
What benefits will get based on the .eml file?

Answer (score 0):

Use directory delivery mode by specifying `specifiedPickupDirectory` as `deliveryMethod` for the `<smtp>` configuration section in your app/web.config. Email files created are in .eml format. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).